# Applescript Issue: "Not Allowed Assistive Access. (-1719)"

Tags: macos, applescript

I wrote the following applescript to open a doc while also hiding some annoying persistent toolbars in my word processor app. It works great when I play directly from script editor. But when I turn it into an app, and try to play in Alfred (not Alfred 2), I get this:

```
Open "Bicycle" is not allowed assistive access. System Events got an error: Open "Bicycle" is not allowed assistive access. (-1719)
```

Oh, and I've tried more ordinary routes than "POSIX", but all bring the same result. Also, I'm running latest version of El Capitan.

```
tell application "Bean"
open POSIX file "/Users/MyDrive/Documents/Bicycle.rtf"

end tell
activate application "Bean"
delay 0.3

tell application "System Events"
tell process "Bean"

    click menu item "Hide Ruler" of menu 1 of menu bar item "View" of menu bar 1

    click menu item "Hide Status Bar" of menu 1 of menu bar item "View" of menu bar 1

    click menu item "Hide Toolbar" of menu 1 of menu bar item "View" of menu bar 1

end tell
end tell
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since

> "Bicycle" is not allowed assistive access

allow it by open
`System Preferences` > `Security & Privacy` > `Privacy` > `Accessibility`
and check the appropriate checkbox.

Comment: Great, thanks! Weird it needs that....I'm just opening a document, not routing anything through any accessibility functionality.  New problem: most launches, I get a pop-up box saying "Press Run to run this script, or Quit to quit". Any idea why?

Comment: Any GUI scripting (in System Events tell a process to do something) needs assistive access. When you save the script uncheck "Show startup screen"

Comment: "Show startup screen" was already unchecked. The pop-up doesn't happen every time.

Comment: What is the appropriate checkbox?

Comment: @Tom The checkbox of the target application which is supposed to appear in the list, or add the application with the plus button.

Comment: Useful to know: every time you re-save the application after an edit, you need to repeat this.